# Add and remove class upon availability of a class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am in the process of adding a class to the parent div if there is a class present in the child div. But simultaneously, want to remove the class from the parent div if the class is not there in the child div.

I have used the below code, that adds the class, but that does not remove the class from the parent when the class is not there in the child div:

```
jQuery(function($){
    if(jQuery(".mtsnb-top").hasClass('mtsnb-shown')) {
        jQuery("body").addClass('test');
    } else if (jQuery(".mtsnb-top").hasClass('mtsnb-hidden')) {
        jQuery("body").removeClass('test');
    }
});
```

Not sure what's the issue here.

I have also added toggleclass method.

```
jQuery(function($){
    if(jQuery(".mtsnb-top").hasClass('mtsnb-shown')) {
        jQuery("body").toggleClass('test');
    }
});
```

But that does not suit my requirement also.

I want, if there is a class **mtsnb-top** present in the child div, then the parent div to have a class **test**, and if the class **mtsnb-top** is absent from the child div, then the class **test** to be removed from the parent div.

Can someone please point where the above code is wrong?

For reference, [this is](https://castlem2.wpengine.com/) the url to the page and the one I am referring is the top notification bar. Want to add a class to the body tag if the bar is showing. If that is hidden, then that class to be removed from the body.

Comment: put your code in `document ready` block and try `jQuery("body").addCLass('test');` instead of `jQuery("body").toggleCLass('test');`

Comment: Sorry, I have modified my code a bit. I have already added the addclass. That adds the class. But the removeclass is not working when the child class is removed

Comment: you have to trigger  event when your child class removed.

Answer (score 0):

You can eliminate the `if/else` statements by using the `toggleClass` method with a second parameter, which adds the class if the second param is true, otherwise removes the class:

```js
var childHasShownClass = jQuery('.mtsnb-top').hasClass('mtsnb-shown');
jQuery('body').toggleClass('test', childHasShownClass);
```

Of course, this means the `body` element will have the `test` class if the child has the `mtsnb-shown` class, otherwise not (even if `mtsnb-hidden` is also not present on the child).

The only other potential issue I see is that `toggleCLass` in your first code example should be `toggleClass`. Lowercase `l` instead of `L`, unless that was just a typo and your actual code is correct.

Comment: It is not adding a class at all :(

Comment: Updated my answer. Make sure you have `.mtsnb-top` in the first line (with the dot at the beginning). My original answer didn't have that, so `jQuery('mtsnb-top')` would not have returned the element at all.

Comment: It is adding the class. But not removing it. Can you please check that?

Comment: Where in your code are you calling this? Are you removing `mtsnb-shown` from the child at some point then calling those code to toggle the class on body?

Answer (score 0):

Find the number of the child elements having the class 'mtsnb-top', then add/remove the class 'test'.

```
if(jQuery('.parent').find('.mtsnb-top').length) {
    jQuery('.parent').addClass('test');
} else {
    jQuery('.parent').removeClass('test');
}
```

Comment: It is adding the class. But not removing it. Can you please check that?